# Arduino YUN doesn't start

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, bootloader

When we start an Arduino YUN board we see the LED RX binking once and then LED ON doesn't work. When we upload the program - it works, but we cannot see the WiFi of Arduino now, and LED ON doesn't work as well.
Is it somehow possible to fully erase the board? Or how to repair this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Once I thought my Yun is dead too, I spent 2 days trying to track down the issue. It was faulty code I've uploaded and it caused my board to run infinite loop, it blocked my serial communication and I couldn't even upload new code via USB. Eventually what worked for me was reseting everything on board and uploading empty sketch via LAN (not USB). Yun has 3 different reset buttons, use them.

- Yún RST
- 32U4 RST
- WLAN RST

Things to investigate are: Bootloader, uploaded Sketch, Board settings. Try uploading empty sketch via ethernet (not usb), it's great advantage of Yun that you can upload new code that way. Simply try to clear everything and then you might fix your Yun. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific. 
1. What program are you uploading?
2. Can you consistently load a sketch onto the Yun?
3. Did you read the Yun page and follow these instructions http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc6 to reset the Yun processors and WiFi?

Comment: Unfortunately I think arduino is broken. I opened topic in Arduino forum and they are not able to help me. If you want to read more: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=d4ik1o5gb6hpkjc5j998rtjto4&topic=199235.0